Google Signed Url Expiry issue
I am facing the issue with google signed URL expiry time. I want to signed URL expire in 5 seconds but its not expiring. here is my python code:
from datetime import datetime,timezone

                expiration_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=5)
                

                bucket = client.get_bucket(settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME)
                blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
                signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=expiration_time)

Even I have tried with this code as well getting same issue
storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        # This URL is valid for 5 seconds
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(seconds=5),
        # Allow GET requests using this URL.
        method="GET",
    )

    print("Generated GET signed URL:")
    print(url)
    print("You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:")
    print(f"curl '{url}'")
    return url

Thanks in advance

I'm unable to reproduce your error. Your code works for me.

The ~code works for me.
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage

export PROJECT="..."
export BUCKET="..."
export BLOB="..."

ACCOUNT="tester"
EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Too broad, but ...
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/storage.admin

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

python3 main.py

main.py:
import logging
import os
import requests
import time

from datetime import datetime,timedelta,timezone
from google.cloud import storage


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

project = os.getenv("PROJECT")
bucket_name = os.getenv("BUCKET")
blob_name = os.getenv("BLOB")


duration: float = 5

storage_client = storage.Client(project=project)
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

url = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    expiration=datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=duration),
    method="GET",
)
logging.info("Received URL")

logging.info("Calling")
logging.info(f"Received: {requests.get(url).status_code}")

logging.info(f"Sleeping: {duration}")
time.sleep(duration)

logging.info("Calling")
logging.info(f"Received: {requests.get(url).status_code}")


Yields:
2024-08-16 10:25:04,374: Received URL
2024-08-16 10:25:04,374: Calling
2024-08-16 10:25:04,503: Received: 200
2024-08-16 10:25:04,504: Sleeping: 5
2024-08-16 10:25:09,504: Calling
2024-08-16 10:25:09,590: Received: 400


It not working even i have used same code as well in my local as well. Some time its expiring some time when url is loaded on browser then its not expiring

I have used same code as well. Please open signed url in browser then see its not expiring in given time

As I showed in my answer, the behavior is correct for me. If I open the link before expiry, I am able to GET the file. If I try again after expiry, I receive a 400 and an ExpiredToken error.

Is there any issue with my gcp configuration. Because mu bucket is public and I am using the json file for google authentication

If the bucket (and the objects) are public then there's no need to "secure" (or not) the objects behind a Signed URL. So, I suspect, you'd never see an expiry. The intent with Signed URLs is to temporarily provide access to anything with access to the Signed URL.

Can you suggest me like my frontend website is running in react and backend in Django, In google bucket we have all media files like images which are using in frontend. So thats why i made bucket to public to frontend app can access the images and there also saved some PDFs as well which i want to make private using signed url like in react app show pdf in pdf viewer and if some go the url then it will be expired, no one can download. SO can you suggest me what i need to do

I feel that I've (a) answered your original question even though you've not acknowledged this; (b) spent more than enough of my time on this issue. Good luck!

Thanks it's resolved with private bucket
